# Why Laravel return array not working with empty() But worked with count()

Tags: php, laravel, count

I am working with laravel framework project and facing below issue.

**Query:**

```
$query = DB::table('test');
$query->select('*');
$query->where('testId = 1');
$result = $query->get();
print_r($result);
```

**Output :**

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Now I am checking `$result` have record or not.

```
if(empty($result))
{
   echo "Not Empty check with empty()";
}

if(count($result) == 0)
{
   echo "Not Empty check with count()";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Not Empty check with count()
```

**Question :**

I have used `empty()` in all the projects but in **laravel framework project** I am not able to know that why this `$result` going in `count()` condition and not going in `empty()`.

Note:

> I have read that count() is slow compare to empty() also empty() check variable is set or not so I am using empty() in all return array or object array.

Please help someone.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your query is returning the result and not empty so count is always greater than zero, check with !empty($result) condition

Comment: But in above case why its going to count() and not going in empty(). This array returns no value from database so !empty() will gives true which is not right. @RAUSHANKUMAR

Comment: as the first() query returns a collection object so better to go with isEmpty() function

Comment: Yes collection object working with count() inbuilt method of php and isEmpty() is laravel method so ofcourse it will work. Thanks for your advice !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `->get()` method, you will get an instance of collection.

When you apply `empty()` on data obtained from get method, you'll notice an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` is always returned, even when there are no results.

When you obtain data with `->get()` method, you can't use following simply,

```
if(empty($data)){ 

}

if(!data){ 

}

if($data){ 

}
```

Instead of above you can simply use,

```
isEmpty($data) or 

count($data) or 

$data->count()
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice !

Comment: I think you shouldn't have problem with `first()` since it will return **null** if no data is found. I wonder why

Comment: I have edit question with get()... Thanks for correction and your answer works and helps lot !

Comment: @RJParikh Congrats, Glad it helped you :D

Answer (score 5):

If you use collection, you sould use `isEmpty()` method

docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-isempty

Comment: Yes correct, So I am able to use count() or isEmpty().. right?

Comment: yep both are ok :)

Comment: Yes, isEmpty() is laravel method and count() php common method. Thanks for your help !

Comment: there is a method ->count() for collection too. no problem

Answer (score 1):

From the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

The laravel collection class implements the [Countable interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) which lets you use the `count` function. If you check the collection class you'll see that the `count` method returns the count of the internal items.

There is no interface for the `empty` function so in this case it only checks if the variable is not set or equals to `false` which obvious doesn't apply in case an object is checked.

Comment: Ok got it... Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Condition Try with this:

```
if(empty($result->toArray()))
{
    echo "Not Empty check with empty()";
}

if(count($result) == 0)
{
   echo "Not Empty check with count()";
}
```